# Customise message notifications in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, organic-groups, emails, notifications

I'm using organic groups with Drupal 7 and members receive email notifications when new content is posted to their group.

However I can't find a way to modify:

```
Email subject: New post in group
Email message: Hello [user], There is a new post called...
```

Which template or database entry do I need to modify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OG7 Uses the Rule module for sending email notifications. See admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/rules_og_group_content_notification

Comment: Thanks.

Someone else had recommended the Mail Editor module but your solution is much cleaner.

Comment: Not only is it much cleaner, it's how OG7 suggests you do it.